# iOS Core Plot "Function transformation" - Y axis only origin

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I cannot find how to do this for a while now, my graph is drawn ok every time but I want to move up my graph, like when you have `f(x) + n`. So, what I want to do actually is change Y origin, so I can draw my (x,0) points. I do not want to draw my points on X axis, I do not see the line that good. I want that my zero Y point actually starts at point three, but not to transform the graph at the same time. Here is picture of what I want to do (see the green line and Y point):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot space `yRange` controls the range of data visible. The image in the question looks like it has a `location` of negative one (-1) and `length` of 18. You can use the `axisConstraints` to keep the x-axis along the bottom of the plot area. If you don't want to use constraints, set the `orthogonalPosition` to the `location` of the `yRange`.